# UIC generated header file does not recognize path to include custom widget header

Tags: qt, qt5, custom-widgets

I made a custom widget plugins library for Qt 5 and it was working fine till I upgraded my OS (to ubuntu 19.04).

In current version (5.12) UIC can not generate the `ui_` header file... Makefile declares custom widget header as a dependency for the cpp file using it:

```
ui_dialog-rectangulation.h: ../anr-0.1.5/src/gui/dialog-rectangulation.ui \
        /usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic \
        qtz/widgets/viewers/image-viewer.hpp
    /usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic ../anr-0.1.5/src/gui/dialog-rectangulation.ui -o ui_dialog-rectangulation.h
```

Though the dependency can not be met:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'qtz/widgets/viewers/image-viewer.hpp', needed by 'ui_dialog-rectangulation.h'. Stop.
```

and the `ui_...` is not generated.

The widget plugin library declares include file like this:

```
QString ImageViewerPlugin::includeFile() const {
    return QLatin1String("qtz/widgets/viewers/image-viewer.hpp");
}
```

The path is correct, header file exists there, though Makefile does not include full path to such file (see above).

Questions:

- Should `Makefile` it include full path? in that case what should I return from `ImageViewerPlugin::includeFile()`?
- In general what am I doing wrong with these widgets? It used to work fine with Qt 5.9 on Ubuntu and Windows. Source code is available at https://github.com/soroush/qtz-widgets, and the plugins library is available at https://github.com/soroush/qtz-plugin